# EM waves in terms of differential forms

Tags: electromagnetism, differential-geometry, classical-electrodynamics, maxwell-equations

I know you can write Maxwell's equations in terms of the four-potential $A = A_{\mu}\mathrm{d}x^{\mu}$, the four-current $j = j_{\mu}\mathrm{d}x^{\mu}$, the exterior derivative $\mathrm{d}$, and the codifferential $\mathrm{d}^{\dagger}$ as:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathrm{dd}A &= 0 \\
\mathrm{d}^{\dagger}\mathrm{d}A &= j
\end{aligned}
$$

and usually you would define $\mathrm{d}A = F$ but I want to stick with the potential for now.

The generalised Laplacian can be written as $\left(\mathrm{d} + \mathrm{d}^{\dagger}\right)^{2} = \mathrm{dd}^{\dagger} + \mathrm{d}^{\dagger}\mathrm{d}$, which I take to mean you want write the EM wave equation as:

$$
\mathrm{dd}^{\dagger}A = -j
$$

which seems to recover the usual $\Box A = 0$ if you expand out $\mathrm{dd}^{\dagger}A$ in components, and set $j=0$ to get the uncharged vacuum limit. However, since the statement $\mathrm{dd}A = 0$ is somewhat redundant ($\mathrm{d}$ and $\mathrm{d}^{\dagger}$ are both nilpotent), doesn't this mean you can just write:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathrm{d}^{\dagger}\mathrm{d}A &= j \\
\mathrm{dd}^{\dagger}A &= -j
\end{aligned}
$$

or even in terms of a commutator

$$
\left[\mathrm{d}^{\dagger},\mathrm{d}\right]A = 2j
$$

It seems right but I'm still a bit shaky on my differential geometry so I wanted to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: the wave equation in the form $\square A=j$ requires the Lorenz gauge condition, $\partial\cdot A=0$. In terms of differential forms,
$$
\partial\cdot A\sim\mathrm d^\dagger A
$$

Moreover, note that
$$
\mathrm{dd}^{\dagger}A \overset?= -j
$$
is not gauge-invariant, so it cannot hold in general.

Comment: How about $(\mathrm{dd}^{\dagger} + \mathrm{d}^{\dagger}\mathrm{d})F = \mathrm{d}j$?

Comment: @gautampk what about it?

Comment: Sorry. Is it the correct gauge invariant wave equation for EM?

Comment: @gautampk ah, yes, that's correct.